# Repeating trials in MatLab

Tags: matlab, repeat, trial, psychtoolbox, experimental-design

i'm am very new to Matlab but really want improve. For my experiment i want to show a picture which the participant response yes/no to, using two different keys (f&g) and then the next picture is presented and it repeats so onward.

Presenting the picture, using the keys works for far, but i can't get it to repeat the trial. Thus my question is how can i get the program to repeat/loop my trial?
Is there something wrong in my code so far or is there additional coding i should use?

this is my code so far

```
function try1_6()

cleanupObj= onCleanup(@() myCleanupFxn);

% PRETEST
% Initialize screen with black background
winID = Screen('openWindow',0, [0 0 0]);

%Parameter
backcol=255;
textcol=0;

% Load image file(s)
structimages= [];
TheImagesdir = dir('theImagesdir/*.jpg');
for i=1: length(TheImagesdir);
    TheImages  = imread(['theImagesdir/' TheImagesdir(i).name], 'JPEG');

    % Get width and height
    imageX = size(TheImages,2);
    imageY = size(TheImages,1);

    % Convert to texture
    myTexture = Screen('MakeTexture', winID, TheImages);

    % Set destination rectangle
    destRect = [50  100  50+imageX  100+imageY];

    %save to structure
    structimages(end+1).filename=TheImagesdir(i).name;
    structimages(end).destRect= destRect;
    structimages(end).texture= myTexture;
end

%Make triallist
numberOfItems= [5]; %list of all possible items
Nrepeats=4;
Response=0;
TrialList=HH_mkTrialList({numberOfItems Response},Nrepeats); 


%PRESENTATION

for trialnum=1:size(TrialList,1)
    nitems = TrialList(trialnum,1);

    Screen('FillRect', winID,backcol); % makes the screen blank

    %displays text
    DrawFormattedText(winID,'dkjfghaslkdfglksdjgfh','center','center',textcol);
    Screen('Flip', winID)
    HH_waitForKeyPress({'space'}); % waits for spacebar to be pressed
    Screen('FillRect',winID,backcol);
    Screen('Flip',winID);
    WaitSecs(1);

    %display picture
    whichTheImages= randi(length(TheImagesdir)); % randomly selects image for directory
    Screen('FillRect',winID,backcol);
    Screen('DrawTexture', winID, myTexture, [], destRect);

    Screen('Flip', winID);
    HH_waitForKeyPress({'f','j'},5)

    if resp==-1
       break
    end 

    TrialList(trialnum,4)= response; %records response

end

end

function myCleanupFxn()
    Screen('CloseAll')
end
```

Comment: One very important thing you forgot to mention is that you are using [Psychtoolbox](http://psychtoolbox.org/) for the screen stuff.

Comment: Also, indent your code properly. The body of `try` and `for` blocks should be indented by a tab. Additionally, don't wrap the whole thing in a giant `try`.

Comment: This is not a complete question. `HH_mkTrialList` and `HH_waitForKeyPress` are both custom methods that you haven't explained what they do. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guideline for posting questions on this site.

Comment: What is the specific error? Describe the problem you are having; what happens exactly and why is it wrong?

Comment: @Setsu It don't not give a specific error, the code does run. The last picture of the directory does open and it responds to the specific key press I specified. However after pressing so,  it all closes, without moving on to the next picture, whereas it should. I think its going wrong because I don't fully get what each line of code does (much of it I get, but not the part that is suppose to code for looping, the "for trialnum=1:size(triallist1) nitems = TrialList(trialnum,1);" bit).

Comment: Variables `resp` and `response` are still used before they are defined. Also, you can't use `myTexture` directly because it will never update itself to other images stored in the structure. Finally, if your code is exiting without errors, then `TrialList` does not contain what you expected it to.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with you code that you need to address. First of all, `TrialList` is used before it is declared/initialized. The `Make triallist` block of code seems out of place in the body of the `for` loop, and should probably be placed before you loop `TrialList`.

Your second problem is the inner `for` loop that loads images. Right now, it loads every image found in the directory, **on every trial!** There is no reason for you to be doing this, and you should be placing this `for` loop outside the trial loop as well. Furthermore, your original code never worked as intended, because you never save the loaded texture anywhere; `myTexture` is overwritten by the last image in your folder and that's the only texture you're ever gonna get. So in addition to pre-loading the images before the loop, you need to save them in a data structure so that you can use them later in your trial loop. A simple `struct` will work nicely here:

```
structImages = [];
TheImagesdir = dir('theImagesdir/*.jpg');
for i = 1:length(TheImagesdir);
    TheImages  = imread(['theImagesdir/' TheImagesdir(i).name], 'JPEG');

    % Get width and height
    imageX = size(TheImages,2);
    imageY = size(TheImages,1);

    % Convert to texture
    myTexture = Screen('MakeTexture', winID, TheImages);

    % Set destination rectangle
    destRect = [50  100  50+imageX  100+imageY];

    %save to structure
    structImages(end+1).filename = TheImagesdir(i).name;
    structImages(end).destRect = destRect;
    structImages(end).texture = myTexture;
end
```

There are other inconsistencies in your code:

1. `whichTheIamges` is defined but not used
2. `resp` is used in the comparison `if resp==-1` but is not defined
3. `response` is saved into `TrialList` before it is defined

Finally, the biggest problem is `Screen('CloseAll', winID);` is inside the trial loop, so you tear down your whole presentation platform after the first trial.

FYI, as noted in my comment wrapping your entire script in a `try` block is really poor practice. I suspect you do this because you want to be able to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> mid-task, but there's a better way to do this. If you make your entire script a function then you can use the `onCleanup` method to execute code whenever your function exits (whether normally, by error, or by interruption). The method goes like this:

```
function myScript()
%//make your script a function. There is an additional advantages to doing this: 
%//function performance is better than script performance.

%//blah-blah-blah

%//setup the cleanup object before opening screen
cleanupObj = onCleanup(@() myCleanupFxn);

%//open the screen
winID = Screen('openWindow',0, [0 0 0]);

%//blah-blah-blah

end

function myCleanupFxn()
    %//local function, not visible outside of this file
    Screen('CloseAll');
end
```

Comment: thank you so much for answering, really. i get most of the comments you made, and clarified for problems for me. i tried to apply your comments the best i could, but unsuccessfully it seems.
i cant seem to include the code in the comment ( i also new to this site) so ill change it in the original question i quess.

Comment: @MDruyvesteyn Please look at the how-to guideline on asking questions. Each question should have something concrete to answer, and not just "my code doesn't work".

Comment: oke, ill try again: how can i get the program to repeat/loop my trial?  ultimately i want to have a picture+key press, repeat this for a number of times and record the key press response